# Binary Search Vector for Closest Value C++

Tags: c++, vector, binary-search, ifstream

Like the title says I am trying to use a binary search method to search a sorted vector for the closest given value and return its index. I have attempted to use lower/upper_bound() but the returned value is either the first or last vector value, or "0". Below is the txt file which i have read the temp and voltage into vectors.

```
1.4 1.644290    -12.5
1.5 1.642990    -13.6
1.6 1.641570    -14.8
1.7 1.640030    -16.0
1.8 1.638370    -17.1
```

This is my current linear search that works

```
double Convert::convertmVtoK(double value) const
{
    assert(!mV.empty());
    auto it = std::min_element(mV.begin(), mV.end(), [value] (double a, double b) {
        return std::abs(value - a) < std::abs(value - b);
    });
    assert(it != mV.end());
    int index = std::distance(mV.begin(), it);
    std::cout<<kelvin[index];
    return kelvin[index];
}
```

This is the algorithm I am currently trying to get working to improve performance.

```
double Convert::convertmVtoK(double value)
{
    auto it = lower_bound(mV.begin(), mV.end(), value);

    if (it == mV.begin())
    {
        it = mV.begin();
    }
    else
    {
        --it;
    }

    auto jt = upper_bound(mV.begin(), mV.end(), value), out = it;

    if (it == mV.end() || jt != mV.end() && value - *it > *jt - value)
    {
        out = jt;
    }

     cout<<"This is conversion mV to K"<<" "<< *out;
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated. I believe the issue may lie with the vector being sorted in descending order but i need the order to remain the same in order to compare the values.

SOLVED thanks to @John. For anyone who needs this in the future here is what works.

```
double Convert::convertmVtoK(double value) const
{

    auto it = lower_bound(mV.begin(), mV.end(), value, [](double a, double b){ return a > b; });
    int index = std::distance(mV.begin(), it);
    std::cout<<kelvin[index];
}
```

Comment: We can't compile your code. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Since your vector is sorted in *descending* order you need to either provide a suitable comparison predicate to lower_bound and upper_bound or use reverse iterators. I don't know which would be least confusing, but you need to do one or the other.

Comment: @john could you point me to anything that can show me how to do either of those?

Comment: @C.Mock `auto it = lower_bound(mV.begin(), mV.end(), value, [](double a, double b){ return a > b; });` or  `auto it = lower_bound(mV.rbegin(), mV.rend(), value);`

Comment: @C.Mock [The documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound).  Please see (2).

Comment: Your dataset has three elements per line. The first column is in strictly ascending order while the last two are in strictly descending order. What's the meaning of these three columns, and what is the lookup?

Comment: @john so using that first function should return an iterator to the closest value? Seems to work thank you. However do I find the correct index without subtracting 1?

Comment: @john actually that works thank you again!

Comment: @C.Mock *However do I find the correct index without subtracting 1* --`std::distance(your_container.begin(), the_iterator_that_was_returned);`  That is the canonical way to return how "far" the iterator is from the starting point.  It works for container other than `vector`, more to the point, iterators where subtracting a value is either undefined or impossible.

Comment: @C.Mock  - Does it? There are some nasty special case / fencepost issues. What if the range is empty? What if the test value is outside the range (extrapolation is often dangerous)? That if the test value is exactly equal to one of the values in the vector?

Comment: Suggestion: post you solution as an answer and mark it as accepted, if you can.

Comment: This is the fourth question on the same problem in 24 hours. Could you please try to work a little longer on your own before asking for our help? Thanks

Comment: I had the same (using std::greater<double>() instead of a lambda) but it's off by one. You specified closest, so need to check abs(diff) for both sides.

Comment: It may have been easier to store all three measures in one structure, so you only have one container, avoiding the std::distance tricks going from a value to an index back to a value. (Or storing only one measure and computing the others from it by formula.)

Answer (score 5):

Since you have a non-increasing range (sorted in descending order), you can use std::lower_bound with a greater than operator, as mentioned in comments. However, this only gets you the first result past or equal to your number. It doesn't mean it's the "closest", which is what you asked for.

Instead, I would use std::upper_bound, so you don't have to check for equality (on double just to make it worse) and then drop back one to get the other bounding data point, and compute which one is actually closer. Along with some boundary checks:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <iterator>

// for nonincreasing range of double, find closest to value, return its index
int index_closest(std::vector<double>::iterator begin, std::vector<double>::iterator end, double value) {
    if (begin == end){
        // we're boned
        throw std::exception("index_closest has no valid index to return");
    }

    auto it = std::upper_bound(begin, end, value, std::greater<double>());

    // first member is closest
    if (begin == it)
        return 0;

    // last member is closest. end is one past that.
    if (end == it)
        return std::distance(begin, end) - 1;

    // between two, need to see which is closer
    double diff1 = abs(value - *it);
    double diff2 = abs(value - *(it-1));
    if (diff2 < diff1)
        --it;
    return std::distance(begin, it);
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> data{ -12.5, -13.6, -14.8, -16.0, -17.1 };
    for (double value = -12.0; value > -18.99; value = value - 1.0) {
        int index = index_closest(data.begin(), data.end(), value);
        std::cout << value << " is closest to " << data[index] << " at index " << index << std::endl;
    }
}
```

output

```
-12 is closest to -12.5 at index 0
-13 is closest to -12.5 at index 0
-14 is closest to -13.6 at index 1
-15 is closest to -14.8 at index 2
-16 is closest to -16 at index 3
-17 is closest to -17.1 at index 4
-18 is closest to -17.1 at index 4
```

Note that, e.g. -14 is closer to -13.6 than -14.8, as a specific counterexample to your current working point. Also note the importance of inputs at both end points.

From there you are welcome to take kelvin[i]. I wasn't happy with using an external data array for the function's return value when you don't need to do that, so I just returned the index.

Comment: Thank you! I will try and implement this now.

Comment: Just thought of this and realized there's no handling for an empty input. Of course, there is no valid return value in that case. I guess I should have returned an iterator.

Answer (score 3):

You might use the following to get the iterator with closest value:

```
auto FindClosest(const std::vector<double>& v, double value)
{
    // assert(std::is_sorted(v.begin(), v.end(), std::greater<>{}));
    auto it = std::lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), value, std::greater<>{});

    if (it == v.begin()) {
        return it;
    } else if (it == v.end()) {
        return it - 1;
    } else {
        return std::abs(value - *it) < std::abs(value - *(it - 1)) ?
               it : it - 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This method works but am not 100% sure it always gives closest value. Incorporated part of @KennyOstrom 's method.

```
    double Convert::convertmVtoK(double value) const
{

    auto it = lower_bound(mV.begin(), mV.end(), value, [](double a, double b){ return a > b; });
    int index = std::distance(mV.begin(), it);

    if(value>mV[0] || value < mV.back())
    {
        std::cout<<"Warning: Voltage Out of Range"<<"\n";
    }

    else if(value==mV[0] || value==mV.back()
            ||fabs(value - mV[index]) <= 0.0001 * fabs(value))
    {
        std::cout<<kelvin[index];
        return kelvin[index];
    }

    else
    {
        double diff1 = std::abs(value - mV[index]);
        double diff2 = std::abs(value - mV[index-1]);

        if (diff2 < diff1)
        {
            std::cout<<kelvin[index-1];
            return kelvin[index-1];
        }

        else
        {
            std::cout<<kelvin[index];
            return kelvin[index];
        }
    }

}
```